# Integer complexity generalization

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, asymptotics

**Introduction**

> "Define $||n||$ to be the complexity of $n$, the smallest number of ones
>   needed to write $n$ using an arbitrary combination of addition and multiplication." Parentheses are allowed. Concatenation of ones is not allowed.
>
> A relevant OEIS sequence: [A005245](https://oeis.org/A005245).

It is [known that](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.2894.pdf) the following bounds hold:

$$
3\log_3 n = \frac{3}{\log 3}\log n\le ||n|| \le \frac{3}{\log 2}\log n = 3\log_2n
$$

The lower bound is optimal, and improving the upper bound is an open problem.

I'm interested in a special case of the following generalization:

### **Definition**

> I call $||n||^h_{A}$ the $h$-order integer complexity of $n$ induced by the set of digits $A\subseteq \mathbb N$.
>
> $||n||^h_{A}$ is defined as the smallest number of elements of $A$ needed to write $n$ using an arbitrary combination of first $h$ hyperoperations and their "opposites". Parentheses are allowed. Concatenation of digits is not allowed.
>
> If we write $h^+$, then the "opposites" are not allowed.

**Hyperoperations**

Are used as [defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation#Definition), and are all binary operations where both arguments must be specified at an expense of two digits (inputs) - except for the *binary successor function* $H_0(a,b)=b+1$ which is not allowed by default, only if $h=0$ or if specified: if we write $h_0$. We do not define an "opposite" for the successor function, but *predecessor* $H^-_0(a,b)=a-1$ could be used.

That is, for $h=0,1,2,3,4\dots$ we are allowed:

- successor, addition, multiplication, exponentiation, tetration, ...

And their "opposites" in default case:

- (predecessor?), subtraction, division, (roots, logarithm), (super-root, super-logarithm), ...

If $A=\{1,2,\dots,b-1\}$ then we say it is induced by number base $b$. Then instead of writing $A$ as a set $\{\dots\}$ we may write just $b$. Notice that it is meaningless to include $0$ in the set.

**For example:**

- $1$-order complexity would allow only addition, subtraction. Trivial (first-order) complexity.
- $1^+$-order complexity would allow only addition. The trivial positive complexity.
- $1^+_0$-order complexity would allow addition and successor. The trivial null-positive complexity.

So notice the definition from introduction $||n||$ corresponds to $2^+$-order integer complexity induced by $A=\{1\}$ (by binary number system) and is written as:

$$||n||^{+2}_{\{1\}}=||n||^{2+}_2$$

Also called as "non-trivial (second-order) positive binary complexity".

For $h\le 2$ only, we say trivial, non-trivial as alternate words to $1$-order, $2$-order.

Also notice if we induce by $A=\mathbb N$, we have $n=n\implies ||n||=1,\forall n$, regardless of $h$.

### **The problem in interest**

> I'm interested in the $2$-order integer complexity induced by some base $b\ge 2$.
>
> $$ ||n||^{2}_b $$
>
> The second-order complexity allows $(+,-,\times,\div)$ operations.
>
> Induced by base is shorthand notation for $A=\{1,2,3,\dots,b-1\}$.

If $b=2$, can we improve the initial bounds, given we now have access to $-,\div$?

We can inherit the upper bound:

$$
3\log_2 n\ge||2||^{2+}_2\ge ||2||^{2}_b
$$

Is it possible to improve this bound and find a lower bound?

My first question is:

> What's the best upper and lower bounds in terms of $n,b$ we can give?

I'm not expecting we can find the optimal bounds since the introduction is still an open problem.

**Limiting case**

If we let $h\to\infty$, does it make sense to analyse $||n||^{\infty}_b$?

There will be arbitrarily large $n$ with complexity $||n||^{\infty}_b=2$ regardless of $b\ge 3$, when applying $H_h(a,b)$ for arbitrarily large $h$, so a lower definite bound can't be better than $2$.

My second question:

> Can we still give an upper bound to this limiting case, depending on $n,b$?

Comment: Because of the rate of growth of the higher order functions, you will find the graph looking even more jagged.  What have you computed so far?  Gerhard "Finds Arithmetic Functions Also Complex" Paseman, 2019.08.18.

Comment: @Gerhard Weak upper bound should be $2\log_b n$ if we allow digits $\le b$ due to Horner's method representation? - For $h\ge 2$ since we use only addition, multiplication in the representation? For the induced by base $b+1$ case.

Comment: Yes, but if you add items that produce large values for few ones, then the graph "dips down" to accommodate those terms. When you have the inverse operation, the graph is less jagged but has more valleys. Gerhard "Rise And Fall Of Representations" Paseman, 2019.08.19.